# Ho to show " Welcome" over div on page load for 5 seconds then show div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.text{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5% 10% 15%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">
   It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

// I intend to show "welcome" over div.text for 5 seconds then show div.text

Answer (score 3):

You can do it use [fadeout](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) and [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Try this:

```js
$("#myElem").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

```html
<style>
  .text {
text-align: center;
padding: 5% 10% 15%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElem" style="text-align: center;
">
  Welcome..!
</div>
<div class="text">
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its
  layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
  using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web
  page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web
  sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
  purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display welcome first and using `setTimeout` hide it and show your text after 5 seconds, like

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.text{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5% 10% 15%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $("div.welcome").hide();
            $("div.text").show();
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="welcome">Welcome</div>
<div class="text" style="display: none;">
   It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```